# Selenium Chrome Driver - Can i set timeout for connecting to driver?

Tags: selenium, timeout, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium tests which requires to invoke first Chrome driver (in my case through "chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\selenum\AutomationProfile")

It's acceptable that the test will fail if the driver is not present - but the problem is it takes more than 30 seconds for the test to fail - probably this is default timeout connecting to the driver?

And - really couldn't find a timeout setting in chrome options - maybe i'm blind

Comment: isn't this site suppose to be open to everyone to ask?

Comment: i asked clear question which just get closed as duplicate - which is not.

Comment: I get the impression the user is asking how to set a timeout in the webdriver.Remote() function call, which seems to be gone about in an unusual fashion to start the remote process anyway. Strangely nobody else is asking this same question about a missing timeout arg in the connection constructor on SO. I'd like to suggest an answer in the form of a question. Why not check that the chromedriver.exe process is running, in code?